# Why does my razor label seem to require a model property to display ViewBag text?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

in an MVC 4 application this works:

```
@if (ViewBag.AdvisoryMessage != null)
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CourseApplication.CourseReason,   (string)ViewBag.AdvisoryMessage )
    }
```

but this doesn't:

```
@if (ViewBag.AdvisoryMessage != null)
{
    @Html.Label((string)ViewBag.AdvisoryMessage ))
}
```

I'd really like to know why. The text in AdvisoryMessage is page-specific and doesn't relate to CourseApplication.CourseReason.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by this doesn't work? Exception? Anything like that? `@Html.Label("some text")` works

Comment: What I mean is that no text is displayed, sorry should have said. But when I used @Html.Label("some text") as a sanity check text was displayed.

Answer (score 0):

A Label is related to something... so it has a "for" attribute.

```
Html.Label(string expression, string labelText, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes);
```

**expression** - Populates the "for" attribute for your label (indicating what it is for). This will also populate the content of the Label if labelText is not present

**labelText** - This populates the content / text for the Label

**htmlAttributes** - This defines all of the specific styles or attributes that you want to add to the element such as class, id, data- attributes, style and more.

Check this uses:

```
@Html.Label("Name")
<label for="Name">
   Name
</lable>

@Html.Label("Name", "First Name")
<label for="Name">
   First Name
</lable>
```

Comment: Agreed, but why doesn't @Html.Label(ViewBag.AdvisoryMessage) result in text displayed on the page, when @Html.Label("Some text") does? I debugged and checked that the string was in the ViewBag.

Comment: Did you try @Html.Label("Some text",(string)ViewBag.AdvisoryMessage)